# Does useMemo have any effect on keyed components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-key-index

When working with a dynamic number of components, React asks developers to provide a unique key, lest this error is thrown:

> Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Say that each child shows a different icon and label based upon some prop. Does the usage of `useMemo` here have any impact on performance?

Comment: Please mark the answer

Answer (score 1):

"useMemo will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed." - from React docs

Given that the elements dependencies (state, props) are still the same and nothing has changed the performance benefit should not be negated.

Comment: You meant "should BE neglected"? If the state and the props are the same, `useMemo` doesn't help, right?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg not sure how you mean that.. let me explain.. when you use useMemo you specify dependencies as the second parameter, only when your component rerenders and some of those dependencies change the value will be recomputed.. this way if a render occurs but none of the dependencies specified changed you will get a memoized value (no recompute)

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Basically it avoids useless re-computations because none of the values that are used in the computation have changed.. the re computation won't occur even tho your component did re-render because some other non relevant state/props changed

Comment: Thank you Smail for your further explanations, but I was particularly referring to how does `useMemo` behave in relation to the keyed component behaviour, which also performs some component caching/ memoization.